# convert my result array into string in php

Tags: php

i want to convert my array into string i mean i want to echo only array value

i use this code

```
$query = "SELECT `message` FROM `appstickers`";
$result    = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$jsonArray  = array();
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $jsonArray[]= $row;             
 }     
 //echo $string;
echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

i get this output

```
[{"message":"welcome to team with us"},{"message":"this is for light dispatch"}]
```

but i want this output

> [welcome to team with us,this is for light dispatch"]

so please give me proper solution with example

Comment: you required output makes no sense at all, it's just a concatinated string as the single element of an array

Answer (score 3):

So why are you using `json_encode()` ?
use `implode()` instead:

```
// ... previous code
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $jsonArray[]= $row;             
 }     
echo '[' . implode(',', $jsonArray) . ']';
```

Comment: i want to send this result to android so i use json_encode

Answer (score 0):

I'm going on a limb here, and assuming your required array is not what you actually want, but you do want this:

```
$jsonArray  = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $jsonArray[]= $row['messsage'];
}
echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

which will result in

```
["welcome to team with us", "this is for light dispatch"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
 echo implode(" ",$jsonArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to use implode() function.

```
$query = "SELECT `message` FROM `appstickers`";
$result    = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$jsonArray  = array();
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $jsonArray[]= $row;             
 }     

//echo $string;
$ans = implode(",",$jsonArray);
echo $ans;
```